# SharePoint 2013 Document Library slow for some users but not all

Tags: error, library

We have a document library on one of our SharePoint sites where some users are unable to access it. It tries to loads and eventually gives up with a error `Something has gone wrong`.

I myself am able to access this library once its loaded. I have the same permissions as the other person who is unable to load it (site owner).

What could be causing this to happen?

Comment: If you have the same permissions on the same library, the only option I see is that the difference lies in how you access the library. Do you both use equivalent environments? Have you considered that the problem may be client side? Maybe this user is working from an office that has a very poor connection - saw that multiple times in the past. Also, the message seems to be pretty generic - "Something has gone wrong" is often reported under connection timeout issues.

Comment: You should probably be considering checking the farm topology - maybe the two clients are served by different web front-ends

Comment: This user is using same URL as I am. They are in same office. I even got them to login to my laptop and the same problem presents itself.

Comment: so, even if the user uses your workstation/laptop the problem is still replicable.  There must be something different between the two users then that trigger some failure / delay on the server side. Can you check the ULS logs? Actually, I have another question too... how many items / lookup does the list have? Any chance the user is hitting a throttling limit?